# After the installation could not see any option to boot Ubuntu

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 64bit as dual boot with Windows 8, UEFI enabled and SECUREBOOT disabled in bios.
After the installation could not see any option to boot Ubuntu. Only windows 8 boots.

I also tried boot repair, please check the link I got during the boot repair completion: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6009260/

Please note, I have disable fast boot from Windows 8 power options.

Answer (score 0):

Although the symptom is the opposite (you boot straight to Windows; he boots straight to Ubuntu), my answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/335377/how-do-i-boot-to-windows-8-from-ubuntu-13-04-on-a-dual-boot-efi-install-no-gru) also applies to your situation.