# Boot from a partition (Windows 8)

Tags: boot, partitioning, windows-8

I'm currently running Windows 8 on an HP Pavilion g7 laptop and I tried installing Ubuntu 13.04 from my flash drive just recently.

Installation went as normal and I created a 50 GB partition for it.  At the end it said I needed to reboot so I pressed OK. A few seconds later an error message popped up and said there was an error and I needed to reboot (or I could stay at the desktop and debug or something). I clicked stay at desktop but it kicked me out into a command line and I really couldn't do anything there so I just held the power button and shut it off. Now I have the partition made (it shows up in Windows as the G: drive), I just have no way to access it without booting from live disk/usb.

Is there some way I can pick which partition to boot from when I power my laptop on?

Edit: Don't know if it helps much but I remember my caps lock key flashing when I was stuck at the command line thing.  (Maybe someone will know what I was at from this?)

Edit: i have a 500 GB disk, and I created the partition in the Ubuntu setup itself.  I'm a little busy but I'll try a few of the suggestions in a little while and see how it goes

Comment: How big is the primary disk?  This is not as dumb a question as you might think....

Comment: (A) How did you create the 50GB partition, from within Windows 8 or during Ubuntu installation? (B) Did you try to install Ubuntu from running WUBI.EXE while Windows 8 was running? Please **edit your question above** with the answers. The solution will depend on the answers to these questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

When I boot up my laptop, i just have to press escape, which brings up a menu.  From there I press f9 and it lets me pick what to boot from.  Maybe this works because I ran boot repair from a live CD.  I'm not exactly sure but this works for me

Answer (score 0):

Although your symptom is the opposite of what's described, my answer to the following question may work for you:

[How do I boot to Windows 8 from Ubuntu 13.04 on a dual-boot EFI install? (No Grub)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/335377/how-do-i-boot-to-windows-8-from-ubuntu-13-04-on-a-dual-boot-efi-install-no-gru)

Also, a minor side note: You probably *don't* want Ubuntu's partition to show up as your `G:` drive in Windows. To fix this, you can launch `gdisk` and change the type code of your Linux partition from 0700 to 8300. See [this page](http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-fs-code/index.html) for more on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very sure if this would help you, but I find your problem somehow similar to mine. I was able to dual boot windows and ubuntu by using boot-repair via liveCD (ubuntu's installer)

Insert your LiveCD, and choose Try ubuntu without installing. Then open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and type this line by line, or just paste it in the terminal

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair

When boot-repair shows up. Just click recommended repair. It'll take a while. By the way, be sure that you're connected to the internet because it'll be downloading stuffs. I'm pretty sure you're to question whether it's working or not because there's no progress bar to know whether it's working well, so open system monitor. Just press the windows key and type it. Now, go to resources tab. You'll see on the network history whether boot-repair is working and downloading. When it's all good. Just follow boot-repairs instructions.

Hope I was of any help